# Monotouch and Async CTP

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, mono, xamarin.ios

Is there any way to hook up these two guys?

The only thing I found is a small article that said as of May 2011 MonoTouch didn't support neither Async CTP nor Reactive Extensions. I don't really care about the second (maybe I should, I dunno), but do you know if is it possible at all? Or when it will be?

Links to manuals, blogs and articles will be appreciated

Comment: I hope your expectations are low.

Comment: Why? I don't know. You're saying it's unlikely to be happen sometime in the nearest future?

Comment: There is already enough in Mono to do basic async work, sure its not eh CTP but its still up for the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mono 'master' (aka 2.11 /unstable) already have most of the **async** support but MonoTouch is *presently* based on Mono 2.10 (last stable release).

However once Mono 2.12 (next stable release) is [available](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Oct-14.html) MonoTouch will be re-based on it, bringing a lot of new [features](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Oct-14.html) in. No promise (when, how, if... ;-) but **async** is one feature that is very popular and multi-core A5 processors makes it even more promising :-)

Comment: so any news WHEN Mono 2.12 (and especially the MonoTouch/MonoDroid supporting async) will be out?

Comment: @TDaver There's a bit more info (even if approximate) in this mailing-list thread http://monotouch.2284126.n4.nabble.com/Await-Async-Task-td4656049.html